# The method 'basename' isn't defined for the type 'Path'. (Documentation)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, basename

This is the Error when u are uploading files to firestore firebase.
So I sol this Error. Checkout the answer below in Answers section. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this Line in Imports **import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;**

Comment: you are a true life savior

Answer (score 2):

import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;
first import this file
then add **Path.** just before baseman()

Comment: Quote the  code for more readability by wrapping specific words with `(backtick)